# Changing order of integration limits

Tags: integration

$$\int_{1}^{3} \int_{0}^y x+y-1 \, dx \, dy = 9$$

How would I change the order of integration here? Wouldn't this require two integrals?

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^3 x+y-1 \, dy \, dx + \int_{1}^{3} \int_{x}^3 x+y-1 \, dy \, dx = 9$$

Why does this integral **below** work?

$$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{x}^3 x+y-1 \, dy \, dx = 9$$

Is this just a coincidence? I'm not sure how to plot this in 3D. Here's a graph of the xy plane and the boundaries of the region on it. This is how I visualized the region. Perhaps I did something wrong?

I am finding the volume between the surface z = x + y and z = 1

[image]

Comment: The region you drew is correct. Whether or not the order of integration limits are reversed, you are integrating over the same exact region. Oh, and +1 for the picture.

Comment: Are you referring to the two part integral or the last integral? The last integral is the one I'm asking about.

Comment: Nice picture, and good analysis.

Comment: @MicroPenguin First and last integral expressions

Comment: for when the integration order could be changed, you may refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem Fubini-Tolleni theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three equalities:

$$\int_{1}^{3} \int_{0}^y x+y-1 \, dx \, dy = 9$$

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^3 x+y-1 \, dy \, dx + \int_{1}^{3} \int_{x}^3 x+y-1 \, dy \, dx = 9$$

$$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{x}^3 x+y-1 \, dy \, dx = 9$$

are correct. However,

$$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{x}^3 x+y-1 \, dy \, dx = \int_{1}^{3} \int_{0}^y x+y-1 \, dx \, dy = 9$$ is ONLY correct because

$$\int_{0}^1 \int_x^1 x+y-1 \,dy\,dx = 0$$

That is the integral evaluated over the little triangle in the bottom left, just below the green, in your picture. That is the difference between the second and third integrals at the start of this post. In general,

$$\int_{0}^{3} \int_{x}^3 f(x,y) \, dy \, dx \neq \int_{1}^{3} \int_{0}^y f(x,y) \, dx \, dy$$

Therefore, this is purely a coincidence and it should be:

$$\int_{1}^{3} \int_{0}^y f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^3 f(x,y) \, dy \, dx + \int_{1}^{3} \int_{x}^3 f(x,y) \, dy \, dx$$

Comment: Fixed some typos on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \int_1^3\!\!\int_0^y x+y+1 \operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y$, integrates over the interval $y\in[1,3], x\in[0,y]$.

As you noted, this is equivalent to the sum of the intervals: $x\in[0,1], y\in[1,3]$ and $x\in(1,3], y\in[x, 3]$

$\displaystyle \int_1^3\!\!\int_0^y x+y-1 \operatorname{d}x\operatorname{d}y = \displaystyle \int_0^1\!\!\int_1^3 x+y-1 \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x+ \displaystyle \int_1^3\!\!\int_x^3 x+y-1 \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x = 9$

---

Note that the integral over the lower corner of the triangle (below y=1) is : $\displaystyle \int_0^1\!\!\int_x^1 x+y-1 \operatorname{d}y\operatorname{d}x = 0$, and hence by coincidence the integral over the entire triangle is equal to that of the truncated triangle (the required interval).

It will not hold in general.